# javascript converting and exploding string to number

Tags: javascript

What can I use to convert this string into a number?  "$148,326.00"

I am guessing that I need to explode it and take the dollar sign off, and then use parseFloat()? Would that be the wisest way?

This is how I am getting the number:

```
var homestead = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("sc2cash");
document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = homestead[1].textContent;
```

Comment: try and let us know if it works

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to remove the dollar signs and commas, (string replace), then convert to a `float` value

Try this:

```
parseFloat('$148,326.00'.replace(/\$|,/g, ''))
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp

Or: http://www.bradino.com/javascript/string-replace/

To handle other currency symbols you could use the following instead (which will remove all non numeric values (excluding a `.` and `-`)):

```
parseFloat('$148,326.00'.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ''))
```

Comment: `/[^0-9\.]+/g` should really just be `/[^0-9.]/g`.

Comment: You may want to pay attention to second solution, that would return the absolute value of a negative number.  `parseFloat('$-148,326.00'.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''))`  will return 148326

Answer (score 5):

```
var s = '$148,326.01';
parseFloat(s.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')); // => 148326.01
```

Comment: i revised the coding a little, im actually pulling the string from an xml.. i should be able to put the var to that right

Answer (score 0):

Will this help

[How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help
[Convert Currency into number format--float/int](http://www.js-x.com/page/javascripts__example.html?view=204)