# javascript parse float error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get sum of rows of my table:

> td1 val = $5,000.00; td2 val = $3000.00;

And I am using the following code:

```
var totalnum = 0;
$('.num').each(function(){
  totalnum+= parseFloat($(this).html());
});
$('.total_num').html(totalnum);
```

This code works perfect if I remove money formatting from the number, otherwise it gives `NaN` as a result even if I am using `parseFloat`.

What am I missing?

Comment: what does .num elements contain? Could you please post an html snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var totalnum = 0;
$('.num').each(function(){
   totalnum+= parseFloat($(this).html().substring(1).replace(',',''));
});
$('.total_num').html('$' + totalnum);
```

This will remove the $ (or whatever currency symbol) from the beginning and all commas before doing the parseFloat and put it back for the total.

Alternatively you could use the [jQuery FormatCurrency](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) plugin and do this:

```
totalnum+= $(this).asNumber();
```

Comment: please check this again, if there is any mistake...  `totalnum+= parseFloat($(this).html().substring(1).replace(',','');`

Comment: What if the value is formatted using european notation `1.000,00`?

Comment: yes i am using jquery format currency, right i could use simply `.asNumber` function. sorry and thanks for help.

Comment: @Pekka It's not in the example and that's what we are going by. Anyway, the formatCurrency plugin can handle that.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `$` to the value, it is no longer an integer, and can no longer be calculated with.

Trying to make the formatted value back into a number is a bad idea. You would have to cater for different currency symbols, different formattings (e.g. `1.000,00`) and so on.

The very best way would be to store the original numeric value in a separate attribute. If using HTML 5, you could use jQuery's `data()` for it:

```
<td class="num" data-value="1.25">$1.25</td>
....

var totalnum = 0;
$('.num').each(function(){
  totalnum+= parseFloat($(this).data("value"));
});
$('.total_num').html(totalnum);
```

this way, you separate the formatted result from the numeric value, which saves a lot of trouble.

Comment: values come from table rows, i am using php money format for that.

Comment: yes i am using html5, but how can i use data-value for calculation?

Comment: i am even using Formatcurrency.js for another and using same jquery function to get total. but its not correct value on formatcurrency applied number, it works perfect for clean numbers.

Comment: @seo yeah. Definitely use clean numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `$` and any other character not part of the float type:

```
var totalnum = 0;

$('.num').each(function(){
    var num = ($(this).html()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
    totalnum+= parseFloat(num);
});

$('.total_num').html(totalnum);
```

Edit: updated `replace` to remove all non-numerical characters (except periods) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript/559178#559178).

Comment: thanks, and what about commas, how can i strip those before calculation?

Comment: What if the data is in Euros? Or Yen?

Comment: You can use the same method to remove any other characters you like: `.replace("$", "").replace(",", "").replace("¥", "");`. There are far more efficient methods of doing this, though.

Comment: @Paperjam the vastly superior approach would be storing the original numeric value in a separate place so one doesn't have to fiddle with it at all. That way, you are safe against yet another currency coming into the equation, or `number_format()` formatting the number in european notation (`1.000,00`), breaking the code later

Comment: @Pekka - True, I didn't think about his original question. If he has access to the original, unformatted values, then he should use those values in his aggregation. As an aside, if he still wanted to use the method he's already using, this answer might help remove unwanted characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript/559178#559178