# Substraction two textbox values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have two textbox as follow:

```
<input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" value="0" />
<input id="discount" name="discount" type="text" value="0" />
```

I want substract discount from amount, and add result to another textbox. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and why you haven't got the result.

Comment: I searched :(, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#result").val(parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10) - parseInt($("#discount").val(), 10));
```

That should do it. jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G8vMd/2/).

Comment: yor code doesn't work in modal popup. I have many input text there.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle example?

Comment: We use primary template for our website, so i can't create such jsFiddle example. But I can explain my situation. I have contract View in mvc application, and when i click button, adding modal popup shown and there are many textboxes,(contract number, company, client etc.), include amount, discount, total amount textboxes. I write your script near their. But in total textbox I get nan value.

Comment: If your text boxes have any non numbers in them, you will get `NaN`. If you are dealing with money, try this instead of using `parseInt` http://stackoverflow.com/a/559178/804665

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JavaScript/Jquery

Suppose your third textbox is

Then your Jquery code will be

```
var vResult = parseInt( $('#amount').val() )  -  parseInt( $('#discount').val() );
$('#result').val( vResult );
```

Comment: Which jQuery event i must be use with your code? Can you create jsFiddle example please?

Comment: You can use click event on submit button.

Comment: Check the example http://jsfiddle.net/G8vMd/3/