# jquery comparing 2 integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My submit click function is as below.
aAmt is a $ field like for eg. $45.00
a_amount is always 10000.
I am converting a_amount to $ in displayCurrencyFormat function.

I am then converting both to parseInt and doing >= comaprison and it fails. Even though aAmt is > $10000 and conition should display alert it doesnt.

```
$("#submitId").click(function () {      
var aAmt = $("#aAmt").val();
var a_amount = "${dAmt}";       

a_amount = displayCurrencyFormat(a_amount);     
var pLen = $("#pOd").val();



if ((parseInt(aAmt) >= parseInt(a_amount)) && (pLen.length == 0)) {
    $('#pDiv').text('Please provide a password');   
    $("#pOd").focus();  
    return false;
}

...//

});


function displayCurrencyFormat(a_amount)
 {
    //convert amount to currency format
    var nbrAmt = Number(a_amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var fmtAmt = '$' + nbrAmt.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");    
    return fmtAmt;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `"${dAmt}"` please?

Comment: ${dAmt} = 10000 comes from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert it into an integer-like data first, and then you can compare them.

The currency formatted input are considered as not a number format so comparing them are something like `String` to `String` comparison, not `Number` to `Number` like what you want to achieve.

Refrence link: [How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that parseInt('$10000') actually giving you "NaN"? 
And as i can see here you are trying to compare integer and string...

Just try to alert aAmt and a_amount variables before you compare them and you will see what is actually going on...