# Using jQuery to extract numbers off HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get just the numbers from these divs, so no "$" or "/BX"

```
 <span class="SRPRef">$6.16/BX</span>
 <div class="Price">$12.32</div>
```

I'm using this jQuery to calculate the percentage but I don't know how to grab just the integers.

```
     var PriceReftxt = $('.Price').text();
     var SRPReftxt = $('.SRPRef').text();

        // CONVERT TO DECIMAL
      var PriceRef = parseInt(PriceReftxt).toFixed(2);
      var SRPRef = parseInt(SRPReftxt).toFixed(2);


         // DO LOGIC BASED MATH
      var Increase = (SRPRef - PriceRef);
     var PercentIncrease = ((Increase / PriceRef) * 100).toFixed(2);

        // FIND EMPTY CELL, AND PUT % NUMBER IN
      $('.SavingsPercent').text("Savings: " + PercentIncrease + "%");
```

Comment: [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) is a thing, and is more suited to your purpose than `parseInt`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get number from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: @billynoah The problem with that one is that it doesn't account for decimal numbers. I know the OP said "integers", but I don't think that's what they meant.

Comment: `string.match(\d+[\.,]?\d*/);` to match both the numbers with decimal point (or comma) and without them. If you are using decimals (as the example in question suggests) you want `parseFloat`, not `parseInt (just as @MikeMcCaughan suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to pull out just the decimals:

```
function extractNumber(string2extract){
    var numberPattern = /[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/g;
    return string2extract.match(numberPattern);
}

var PriceReftxt = extractNumber($('.Price').text());
var SRPReftxt   = extractNumber($('.SRPRef').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx perhaps?

```
$('.Price').text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
 var number = parseInt(Price, 10);
 $('.SRPRef').text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
 var number2 = parseInt(SRPRef, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could is replace both of those (`"$"` and `"/BX"`) with an empty string which will effectively remove them if they exist:

```
myString = myString.replace("$", "").replace("/BX", "");
```

For example if `myString` was the value `"$6.16/BX"`, this would make it `"6.16"`.

Or you could make a function that strips everything but numbers and periods. For example:

```js
function getNumerFromString(str)
{
  return str.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"");
}

console.log(getNumerFromString("$6.16/BX"))
console.log(getNumerFromString("$12.32"))
console.log(getNumerFromString("abc$1.00def"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As often when trying to parse things, use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Made an example with your tag classes. If you want to actually do some math, just `parseInt` the results

```js
// get our numbers
var res1 = $(".SRPRef").text().match(/\d*\.?\d+/);
var res2 = $(".Price").text().match(/\d*\.?\d+/);

// show our results
$(".result").html(res1 + "<br>" + res2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="SRPRef">$6.16/BX</span>
 <div class="Price">$12.32</div>

<h4>results:<h4>
<span class="result"></span>
```