# Price String spliting into amount and currency

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need help splitting string in javascript.

I have a string with currency. The string depends on the location.

**For example:** "1,99€" or "$1,99"

I would like to split the string and extract the "amount" and the "currency" out of it.

If this fails, I would like to return an empty string or just null.

Does someone know how to solve that?

Comment: What did you try that failed?

Comment: At the moment i dont even know where to start

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Search, and research".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect all inputs to include both decimals of the cent value (ie, your comma will always be followed by 2 digits) you could use this:

```
const amount = money.match(/\d/g).join('') / 100;
const curren = money.match(/[^\d,]/g).join('');
```

JavaScripts much hated implicit type coercion allows us to divide that string numerator by a number denominator and end up with a number.

To get the currency, we simply extract all non- digit or comma characters and join them.

If you can't rely on the input including the cent value (ie, you might receive a whole dollar amount without a comma or cent digits) try this:

```
const amount = money.match(/d/g).join('') / (money.includes(',') ? 100 : 1);
```

Comment: And if it does not have a decimal?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to match and replace using regex

```js
var extractMoney = function(string) {
  var amount = string.match(/[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?/)
  var unit = string.replace(/[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?/, "")
  if (amount && unit) {
    return {
      amount: +amount[0].replace(",", "."),
      currency: unit
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(extractMoney("1,99€"));
console.log(extractMoney("$1,99")); 
console.log(extractMoney("error"));
```

results

```
extractMoney("1,99€"); // => {amount: 1.99, currency: "€"}
extractMoney("$1,99"); // => {amount: 1.99, currency: "$"}
extractMoney("error"); // => null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to get `amount` and `currency` symbol from the **string with currency**

```js
var price = '1,99€';
//var price = '$1,99';
var amount = Number( price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var currency = price.match(/[^\d,]/g).join('');
console.log(amount);
console.log(currency);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use regular expressions, there's a post here:  [How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript) that should cover your needs:

```
var currency = "GB$13,456.00";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

but different cultures write the decimal points in different ways, some use commas, some use full stop, so you might need to tweak the expression if you have to handle these cases.

Answer (score 0):

For a comprehensive solution I would look into leveraging an existing library like money.js:

http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/

This would be more appropriate for a real world product, but I'm not sure if you are doing this as a learning exercise or something else.