# How to compare currency to double in handlebars

Tags: html, css, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am using Handlebars.js and I am trying to compare the price of each product to see if it is over $35. If so, I will display text beneath. The problem is that the price is stored as "$54.99", so when compared to a number it is treated as 0. How can I compare these two values?

Here is my code so far:

```
{{#gt price.without_tax.formatted 34.99}}
  This product qualifies for free shipping!
{{else}}
  Not free shipping
{{/gt}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numeric field is accessed via:   price.without_tax.value

Use that instead of price.without_tax.formatted and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. BigCommerce does not allow helpers, so this was the best solution, otherwise the JS solution would have also worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with handlebars itself, but with a data you are passing to comparison, in this example `price.without_tax.formatted`.

Of course you can convert the price according to this answer: [How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)
but anyway you should have raw price (as number) somewhere stored. If no- then there is application design issue I believe.

Comment: I have not been able to locate anywhere that there is a raw price unfortunately. I saw the question you linked, but how can I take that value from handlebars and use it in a JS equation?

Comment: I understand that you cannot register handlebars helpers?

Comment: As @MaciejKwas said you have to create a helper and put your JS code in. Then use the helper you've created in your handlebar template to compare the results.