# How to get the exact element price?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble getting the exact price off of this html code :

```
<span id="price" data-selenium-price="1094.4">$1,094.40</span>
```

Below is what I used to get the exact price but it resulted in the value `1` rather than the value `1094.4` :

```
function() { 
    try { 
        return document.querySelector("#price").innerText.match(/^.{1}(.*).{0}/i)[1].trim(); 
    }
    catch(e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I can do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the regex necessary for your requirements?

Comment: You can easily take out the `data-selenium-price` value if that's always the same

Comment: It works somehow please check: https://jsfiddle.net/1ce4xm4h/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: For the record, your regex reads "Any character. Then capture zero or more characters. Then match any character zero times." It... makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```js
    
var price = document.getElementById("price").innerText.replace(/[$]/,'').replace(/,/,'');
console.log(parseInt(price));
```

```html
<span id="price" data-selenium-price="1094.4">$1,094.40</span>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this using DOM scraping

Comment: Anytime I try an enter it I get the error message `The javaScript must define a function with a return value.`

Comment: Please give the reason for down voting

Comment: My mistake, didn't realize I down voted it. Please edit the answer and I'll up vote it.

Comment: I'm still new to programming - whats SO? Also, what is a regular expression I can use to remove the decimals all together? `/^.{1}(.*).{0}/i`

Comment: I just meant Have you ran my code snippet in StackOverflow? try **Run code snippet**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156381/discussion-between-jamesrocky-and-being-sunny).

Answer (score 1):

If the `data-selenium-price` and the innerText value is same, you can take out the attribute value.

```js
function price() {
  try {
    console.log(document.querySelector("#price").getAttribute("data-selenium-price"));
  } catch (e) {
    return "";
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="price" data-selenium-price="1094.4">$1,094.40</span>
<button type="button" onclick="price()">Get Price</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be pulling anything using that unfortunately. Originally the code I used, it seemed as though it stopped showing anything after the "," in 1,094.40 - which is why I'm wondering now if I can remove the "," using the original code I used.

Comment: As I said in the above answer, if you have always the attribute `data-selenium-price` available get the Attribute value instead of innerText if they are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to use the attribute data-selenium-price then try this

```js
console.log(parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerText.slice(1).replace(/,/g, '')));
```

```html
<span id="price" data-selenium-price="1094.4">$1,094.40</span>
```

See the value in console

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using this seemed to have solve my inquiry:

```
function() { 
    try { 
        return document.querySelector("#price").innerText.match(/^.{1}(.*).{0}/i)[1].replace(",", '').trim();
    }
    catch(e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```