# Convert a currency to a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting, data-conversion

I have strings in currency format which i have to convert to float without using any js library.

`2 079,15 EUR` as an example should return `2079.15`

Is there a simple way to do it ?

> the solution proposed in [How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript) is not working in this case:
>
> As it will return `207915` in case of `2 079,15 EUR` instead of `2079.15`
>
> And will return `2079` in case of `2 079 EUR`
>
> A working solution should return even:
>   `207915` in the 1st case and `207900`in the 2nd case
>   or `2079.15` in the 1st case and `2079`in the 2nd case.
>
> The solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/559178/1086682 works in case of local "US" or "en-GB" **but does not work for "FR"**.
>
> [Proof](https://jsfiddle.net/n8v7gxjd/2/)

Comment: You should not use any floating point values for currency. Ever. Only integers, i.e. cents instead of dollars (similar for other currencies). Integer math is safe up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, floating-point based math never is (famous 0.1+0.2).

Comment: can you please clarify your answer ?

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers, use integers. Use cents, not dollars.

Comment: why are you talking about dollars ? your comment is not helping me getting the desired result in any way

Comment: @HassanALAMI, don't edit the answer into the question.

Comment: DO NOT USE FLOATING POINT FOR CURRENCY! USE INTEGERS! -- There - easier to understand now? Of course you could just read what I already wrote. It's very, very simple English. You keep asking "How do I hit myself on the head, very hard" and I keep telling you not to do that.

Comment: i'm asking for float numbers in very simple English.

Comment: Möre, although you should never store a currency as a float you need to convert a string to a float, multiply it with 100 and then convert it to an integer. So you’ll need to convert the string to a float at some point. Unless you want to fuddle around with arrays that is...