# Subtract 1 from variable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having some trouble getting this right. I'm very new to jQuery, so trying to get better and learn.

Currently I am getting 2 different values from a html table using the following code

```
var sellPrice = $('.qt').find("tr:eq(2)").find("td:eq(4)").html();
var buyPrice = $('.break .main-col .qt').find("tr:eq(2)").find("td:eq(4)").html();
```

These both output a value such as $13,000,000
I am then wanting to subtract 1 from these values (making it $12,999,999) before pasting them to an input as such

```
$('input[name="sell"]').val(sellPrice);
$('input[name="buy"]').val(buyPrice);
```

However, I am having some trouble with how to subtract $1 from these. 
I tried using `sellPrice--;` but without success. 
I've also tried adding `- 1;` at the end of each variable, but did not succeed either.

I tried to test something like this, but did not work either.

```
var minusOne = -1;
var getCurrentSellPrice = $('.qt').find("tr:eq(2)").find("td:eq(4)").html();
var getCurrentBuyPrice = $('.break .main-col .qt').find("tr:eq(2)").find("td:eq(4)").html();

var sellPrice = (getCurrentSellPrice - minusOne);
var buyPrice = (getCurrentBuyPrice - minusOne);

$('input[name="sell"]').val(sellPrice);
$('input[name="buy"]').val(buyPrice);`
```

Trying my best to familiarize myself with jQuery :)
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this

```
var getCurrentSellPrice = $('.qt').find("tr:eq(2)").find("td:eq(4)").html();
var getCurrentBuyPrice = $('.break .main-col .qt').find("tr:eq(2)").find("td:eq(4)").html();

var sellPrice = Number(getCurrentSellPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")) - 1;
var buyPrice = Number(getCurrentBuyPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")) + 1;

$('input[name="sell"]').val(sellPrice);
$('input[name="buy"]').val(buyPrice);
```

Comment: might also be worth calling `.text()` rather than `.html()` as a "best practice"

Comment: @DacreDenny I've tried using `.text()` but for some reason the output isn't correct for this. Will keep in mind for future, though. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting - thanks for letting me know. All the best with your project :-)

Comment: @DacreDenny Probably something to do with the site's code. It's not mine you see. And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers contain currency symbol and are strings, you need to convert them to proper numbers before subtracting them. See the answer below.

[How to convert a currency string to a double with jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Awesome. Figured it was something like this. I've solved this and will post my new code! Thanks so much, Jay.

Comment: @JanHenning Happy to help.