# Parse property from object when request data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting a product list from a JSON file like

**products.service**

```
getProducts(): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this._http.get<Product[]>(this.configUrl); 
}
```

**products.component**

```
getProducts(): void{
    this.productsService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(productList =>{
         this.products = productList['products'];
        } );

}
```

**product.interface**

```
export interface Product {
    "quantity": number;
    "price": number;
    "available": boolean;
    "sublevel_id": number;
    "name": string;
    "id": string;
}
```

**Json example**

```
0:
 available: false
 id: "58b5a5b1b6b6c7aacc25b3fb"
 name: "aute"
 price: "$8,958"
 quantity: 308
 sublevel_id: 3
1:
 available: true
 id: "58b5a5b117bf36cf8aed54ab"
 name: "mollit"
 price: "$5,450"
 quantity: 891
 sublevel_id: 3
```

Price property is stored in json as string but I would like to store it in my variable `this.products` as a number because I will operate with them several times

How is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why not storing price on JSON as a number?

Comment: Anyway, this seems a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: @GCSDC I cannot change the format of the json file and is not the same because I know how to parse from string currency to float number (`parseFloat(p.price.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ''))`) but I want to store it directly as a number so I don't need to use that function each time I want to operate with it

Answer (score 1):

Per your last comment, here's what you could do to store the values as desired in one go:

Replace:

```js
this.products = productList['products'];
```

with:

```js
this.products = productList['products']
  .map(product => ({ ...product, price: Number(product.price.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,'')) }));
```

I used the solution given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript) to convert the currency value to a floating point number, as also mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Store price in number format, instead of string.

```
0:
 available: false
 id: "58b5a5b1b6b6c7aacc25b3fb"
 name: "aute"
 price: 8958
 quantity: 308
 sublevel_id: 3
1:
 available: true
 id: "58b5a5b117bf36cf8aed54ab"
 name: "mollit"
 price: 5450
 quantity: 891
 sublevel_id: 3
```