# Convert currency compact notation (e.g. '$1.5k') into integer (e.g. 1500)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a column with different currencies and ways to write numbers that I want to convert to numbers, ex:
$1.5M
€1.5B
$1.5B
$1.5k
€1.5k
$1.5K

All the .tests I run on my regex return false. I think the issue is that the value returned has square brackets but I don't know how to take only the number.
When I put a log, it shows: Info    [1.5] and not Info  1.5

```
    function ConvertToInteger (Sheet,columnToConvert) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet);  
  var shLastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var shdata = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var regExp = new RegExp('[.,0123456789]+');
  
  var regExpBillionDollar = new RegExp('[\$][.,0-9]+[B$]','g');
  var regExpMillionDollar = new RegExp('[\$][.,0-9]+[M$]','g');
  var regExpKiloDollar = new RegExp('[\$][.,0-9]+[K$]','g');
  var regExpBillionEuros = new RegExp('[\‎€][.,0-9]+[B$]','g');
  var regExpMillionEuros = new RegExp('[\‎€][.,0-9]+[M$]','g');
  var regExpKiloEuros = new RegExp('[\‎€][.,0-9]+[K$]','g');  


  
  for (var i = 1; i < shLastRow; i++) {
    
    var DataConverted = regExp.exec(shdata[i][columnToConvert])
    if (regExpBillionDollar.test(DataConverted))    {
    sh.getRange(i+1, columnToConvert+1).setValue((DataConverted *1000) * 0.9); //Convert to Euros
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do both (convert to integer and get exchange rate product) within one function, you can make use of [`String.prototype.replace()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) which [accepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) callback function as its second argument. You may have this function to process [matching groups](https://regex101.com/r/zOvaHk/1) (`([\$\€])` - currency, either dollar or euro; `(\d+.\d+)` - floating point number, i.e. 1.5; `([K,M,B])` - respective suffix) in a way that

- suffix is turned into multiplier (10 in power of 3, 6, 9, which corresponds to value of respective object key `{'K': 10**3, 'M': 10**6, 'B': 10**9}`
- currency character is turned either into `1` (for dollar) or `1.16` (exchange rate for euro)

To cast resulting string into number, you may simply prepend `+`, to drop decimal part (equivalent to `Math.floor()`), you may use `0|`:

```js
const src = ['$1.5M','€1.5B','$1.5B','$1.5k','€1.5k','$1.5K', '$800'],
      exRateToDollar = {'$': 1, '€': 1.16}, 
      
      translate = (s, exchangeRate) => 
        0|+s
          .toUpperCase()
          .replace(
            /^([\$\€])(\d+(\.\d+)?)([K,M,B])?$/, 
            (_, currency, n, __, suffix) =>           
              exchangeRate[currency]*
              n*
              (suffix ? {'K':10**3, 'M':10**6, 'B':10**9}[suffix] : 1))
        
console.log(src.map(s => translate(s, exRateToDollar)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks Yevgen. Sorry I guess I'm too much of a newbie to understand what you wrote and how to add it to my function. And I need to convert each currency to euros, hence why if the test returns true, it multiplies the dollars by 0.9 to have euro integers

Comment: Great thanks Yevgen. A lot easier to understand for me ;)